# Rails - Safari Making Extra Request via AJAX-enabled Link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, safari

I built a table that has buttons at the bottom to load a number of additional rows through data-remote="true". This get passed to the controller, there is a format.js response, and jquery appends to the table. Everything is working fine except for one thing. Safari seems to be doing some kind of...eager loading of the first URL it encounters? This problem does not occur in Chrome or Firefox.

My HTML links look like this:

```
<a turbolinks="false" data-remote="true" href="/users/name?expand=5">5</a>
<a turbolinks="false" data-remote="true" href="/users/name?expand=50">50</a>
<a turbolinks="false" data-remote="true" href="/users/name?expand=500">500</a>
```

When I visit my "/users/name" route, I see:

```
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
Processing by UsersController#show as JS
Parameters: {"id"=>"name"}
Parameters: {"expand"=>"5", "id"=>"name"}
Rendering users/show.html.erb within layouts/application
Rendering users/show.js.erb
```

Both the HTML and JS responses are served. This queries my database twice (first for the initial data, then the additional five rows). Only the initial data is (correctly) rendered on the page.

Why is ONLY Safari making this request before it's even being asked for by clicking the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's weird, but I'm pretty sure I figured this out. Safari is trying to be helpful by pre-fetching the data for a link that I usually click when I'm on that page (which is being clicked a lot right now, because I'm testing it).

In my first example, you can see that "expand => 5" is always being called. I clicked the "expand => 50" link 10 times, then tried to hit the "/users/name" route. Now, every request looks like:

```
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
Processing by UsersController#show as JS
Parameters: {"id"=>"name"}
Parameters: {"expand"=>"50", "id"=>"name"}
```

It's an extra query sometimes but I guess it doesn't hurt. If anything, it's getting my database to cache a request that's semi-likely to happen.